# Android UDP Socket Communication (CLIENT SERVER BEHIND DIFFERENT ROUTERS)

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, client-server

Issue is between communication ONLY.

I want to demonstrate the communication(streaming) of data between two mobiles with Dynamic IP(Behind Different Routers) through Internet

***Client(A[192.168.1.22]) <--> NAT(ROUTER[192.168.1.1]) <---> Internet(S-MyServer[62.68.45.111]) <---> NAT(ROUTER[192.168.0.1]) <---> Client(B[192.168.0.44])***

**A<-->S<-->B**

one mobile**(Client A)** will send recorded voice data to **server(S)** and other **Client(B)** will fetch stream data and play in earphone from **Server(S)** and same for the Client(B) to Client(A).(Just like VOIP)

I have done with voice call over Wifi with direct communication between two android mobile devices(BOTH WITH STATIC IP AND SAME NAT(ROUTER)) but want over internet is this possible? suggest me.

When I am trying to communicate the issue is Server(S) is not able to send any data to Client(B) as the port is not forwarded, and don't want to forward port.

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for bad English .

Comment: Have you set up a virtual server entry in your router for the unicast port you want to push forward to (or port triggering for a range of port numbers) over Internet? If you did, but still you face a problem, does your Internet service provider block certain ports?

Comment: To perform a port forwarding to expose it as a public Internet port at router's gateway, you still need a static private IP address of the private host that provides the service port...It will be difficult for a dynamic private IP address since it will change after its lease expires.

Comment: Is any other way to except port forwording.